# $x^{\frac{p-1}{2}}+1$ is reducible in $\Bbb Z_p[x]$

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let $p$ be an odd prime. Prove that the polynomial $f(x) = x^{\frac{p-1}{2}}+1$ is reducible in  $\Bbb Z_p[x]$ and factor $f(x)$ into irreducible polynomials in $\Bbb Z_p[x]$.

I've been struggling this problem. If $\frac{p-1}{2}$ is odd, then $-1$ is zero of $f(x)$, I think there must be a relationship between $x^2+1$ and $x^{\frac{p-1}{2}}+1$ when it comes to $\frac{p-1}{2}$ is even.

My question :

1. Is there a solution when "$x^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$ is even?"
2. How could I show that $f(x)$ is factored into irreducible polynomials?

Comment: Hint: Recall that the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}/p)^\times$ is cyclic of order $p-1$.

Comment: @DouglasMolin That's what I've already used, "The little Theorem of Fermat". Could you explain me how to use your "Hint"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x) = x^{\frac{p-1}{2}}+1$ factors completely over $\mathbb Z/(p)$:
$$
x^{\frac{p-1}{2}}+1 
= \frac{x^{p-1}-1}{x^{\frac{p-1}{2}}-1}
= \frac{\prod_{a=1}^{p-1} (x-a)}{\prod_{a=1}^{\frac{p-1}{2}} (x-a^2)}
$$
This follows from [Euler's criterion for quadratic residues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion).

Answer (score 2):

Over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$, the polynomial $x^{p-1}-1$ splits into linear factors, as any nonzero element is a root. Now we have
$$
x^{p-1}-1=(x^{\frac{p-1}{2}}-1)(x^{\frac{p-1}{2}}+1),
$$
which implies that the two factors also are a product of linear factors  over $\Bbb F_p$.

Comment: So, since every element in $\mathbb F_p$ is zero of $f(x)$, the two factors must have some linear factors..

Comment: But, now then, how can I factor f(x) into irreducible factors? How could I distinguish which of the two factors each will be divided by linear factors?

Comment: @Hobby No, $x^{p-1}-1=x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots (x-p+1)$ splits into linear factors, so **all** factors of $x^{\frac{p-1}{2}}-1$ are linear.

Comment: I mean, then how could I know which of those linear factors divide $x^{\frac{p-1}{2}}+1$? Could there be some linear factors divide $x^{\frac{p-1}{2}}-1$ such as 1?

Comment: Yes, definitely $1$ is a root of the first factor, and not of the second, if you write $x^{p-1}-1=g(x)h(x)$ as above. But think of your title question. We have solved this, because all factors are linear, and hence irreducible. We need not know, exactly which roots $h(x)$ has. Only, that it is reducible.